# Error while installing VSFTPD in passive mode - 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, vsftpd

I am trying to install and connect to FTPS server (passive mode) locally. I have read similar topics in this community, but still can't fix the problem or find an error in the `vsftpd.conf`. Firewall is disabled, socket `192,168.1.90:21` answers to ping (can connect via telnet). Could you help me solve this?

Here's my configuration (uncommented lines):

```
listen=YES
listen_address=192.168.1.90
listen_port=21
listen_ipv6=NO

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
setproctitle_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
syslog_enable=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

connect_from_port_20=NO

chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.users
userlist_deny=NO

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=20021
pasv_max_port=20024
```

Output of `lsof -i:21`:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
vsftpd  15054 root    3u  IPv4 228839      0t0  TCP ex-srv:ftp (LISTEN)
```

Comment: That looks like FTPS (FTP with SSL/TLS), not SFTP (a SSH-based file transfer protocol). In passive mode, the FTP(s) server needs to open a second listening socket for the data connection. Your configuration allocates only the small range of 20021...20024 for this. If some other application already occupies these ports, the FTP server can accept a login but cannot transfer data or directory listings in passive mode.

Comment: @telcoM so you mean that I have to configure wider range of ports?

Comment: Or try and figure out why those ports don't seem to be available, e.g with `lsof -i tcp:20021` and so on, for each port in the `pasv_min_port`...`pasv_max_port` range.

Comment: @telcoM doesn't work, i even tried to reinstall completely vsftpd with conf file, changing only `listen=NO` to `YES` and tried command `vsftpd`, but stil same error. I think problem is that vsftpd can't reach configuration file for some reason, because even logging doesn't work though i enabled it.

Comment: ```root@ex-srv:/etc# ls -l | grep vsftpd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       5849 cze 27 01:09 vsftpd.conf
```

Are permissions and owner set properly?

Comment: By the permissions, *everyone on the system* will be able to read the configuration file (assuming the root directory and the `/etc` directory have standard permissions), so permissions are sufficient and the owner is not the problem.